# dpdk VMware net_vmxnet3 socket(-1)

Tags: dpdk

```
[root@localhost helloworld]# dpdk-devbind.py -s

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:13:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' drv=vfio-pci unused=vmxnet3
0000:1b:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' drv=vfio-pci unused=vmxnet3

[root@localhost helloworld]# ./build/helloworld
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 8
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(3)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_vmxnet3 (15ad:7b0) device: 0000:13:00.0 (socket -1)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(3)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_vmxnet3 (15ad:7b0) device: 0000:1b:00.0 (socket -1)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 3
hello from core 4
hello from core 5
hello from core 6
hello from core 7
hello from core 0
```

How to fix "EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_vmxnet3 (15ad:7b0) device: 0000:13:00.0 (socket -1)" problem? i'm really confuse with prob